# Missing deploy.cmd when building website

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, webdeploy

I have an old website that is being deployed to a server by teamcity.
Previously, this has been done by invoking the build target MSDeployPublish.
All the other sites being deployed from teamcity use Package and then a separate build configuration to deploy by invoking the generated cmd file.

But, this one site does not make a cmd file when built.
The package zip file does contain an `Archive.deploy.cmd` file, but `Project.deply.cmd` is missing from the Package output directory.

I have been comparing this project to a couple other that work, but am unable to find the root cause.

One that works:

[image: teamcity artifacts dropdown]

And the one that doesn't work:

[image: teamcity artifacts dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I cracked it;

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
 <Optimize>true</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
-<PackageAsSingleFile>false</PackageAsSingleFile>
-<ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>true</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
-<ExcludeApp_Data>true</ExcludeApp_Data>
-<PublishDatabases>false</PublishDatabases>
-<DeployIisAppPath>Partnerportal</DeployIisAppPath>
-<DesktopBuildPackageLocation>obj\Release\Package\Project.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
-<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
+<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I suspect it is likely the `PackageAsSingleFile` that caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks for share the solution, please accept it as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities who have the similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I was going to, just have to wait a couple days before I am allowed to do so :)